# Temporary Index for a while loop

Tags: c#

I have a loop with an index. But the index jumps up and down from time to time, so a for loop is out of the question. But I still need the index. I just don't like the idea of having a temporary index in my function which I am only using for one loop. e.g.

```
...
int i = 0;

while( i < something)
{
  if(a)
    i++:
  else
    i--:
}

...
```

Can I make i temporary for the loop? Maybe something like this?

```
...
temporary (int i = 0)
{

  while( i < something)
  {
    if(a)
      i++:
    else
      i--:
  }
}
...
```

Comment: Can you share your thoughts about the problem of having a variable used _only_ for a loop? Honestly I don't see the problem nor I can't understand your concern about it.

Comment: How about `do...while` loop?

Comment: it's not possible, because int is not Disposable , anyway garbage collector handles this, you don't need to worry about it

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < something; /* nothing here */) { if (a) { i++; } else { i--; } }`

Comment: @Marco The loop is inside a long method which I cannot split up. So any var accessible will reduce  clarity. (I'm working with VS and if autocorrect suggests 'i' I have no context for it.)

Comment: @LeVu `do while` works differently, it won't skip the first iteration if `something == 0`

Comment: @Cid I didn't knew you could leave the third part out. Works for me. Thanks :D

Comment: @GoldenDremora Now you do :p you can leave blank any parts, they are just *initialization*, *post operation* and *exit condition*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `for loop` in order to achieve this. the variable i will live only inside the `for loop` scope.

```
for (int i = 0; i < something;;)
{
  if(a)
     i++:
  else
     i--:
  }
}
```

Comment: In most languages, there is a clear difference between while-loops and for-loops. C and its "friends" abuse for-loops to be while-loops. Learning this way of working can be contraproductive if you ever need to switch to other languages, where this abuse is not that common.

Answer (score 2):

You can limit the range of a variable by enclosing its declaration and its use within curly braces. It looks a litte bit strange, but it works fine.

Then your `i` variable can't be accessed outside of this scope as shown below (you will get a compilation error) :

```
MyMethod()
{
  // ... lots of code here

  { 
    int i=0;

    while( i < something)
    {
      if(a)
        i++;
      else
        i--;
    }  
    i--; // ok
  } 

  i--; // error : The name 'i' does not exist in the current context

  // ... some more code here
}
```